# Why was the question asking "How to locate ATC recordings of a specific flight" closed?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, closed-questions, vote-to-close

My [first question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/87295/are-belarusian-atc-recordings-available-for-ryanair-flight-4978) in this SE site was closed not too long ago, with the reason:

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> This question does not appear to be about aviation, within the scope defined in the help center.

I went through the off-topic reasons in the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but couldn't find any reason for the question to be closed.

Was it only because it became a hot-network-question, so it got so many views, it would inevitably get the needed close votes?

Or was maybe too specific? Because the original version asked about how to locate ATC recordings for specific flights in general, a later edit (not by me) made it about the specific incident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed the hyperlinks in the banner you'll arrive [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This falls under "resource location", which is off-topic here as the Stack Exchange model isn't the best fit for it.

Now, if you asked *why* instead of *where/how,* then this should help: [Why is it the ATC recording of Ethiopian Airlines Flight 302 is not yet available online?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/61189/14897) (it would also IMO be a duplicate).

The closure was [unanimous from the review queue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/57921), so it's not about being a promoted hot topic with lots of visitors (all the voters are long-time Aviation users).

As of writing this the top voted answer is also very much like the answer I linked to (the possible duplicate).

Comment: Well I tried to make it general, by asking how one can locate the resource, but the question was later edited. Anyway [aland's comment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/87295/are-belarusian-atc-recordings-available-for-ryanair-flight-4978#comment231757_87295) basically answers the question, so I guess the main objective of the question has been fulfilled.

Comment: @user000001: It would have eventually turned up -- upside is you got yourself some sweet hot topic points :-)

Comment: So-- in your opinion, is *this* (upvoted question) also a question that also should be closed for being a case of "resource location"?  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/83224/34686r  .  Note the (upvoted) comment from RalphJ-- "And, to pre-empt objections about "resource location is off-topic," the real question here is about a method: how to go about researching retired procedures. And that's a perfectly valid question - because the answer isn't to go buy them from Amazon or from Sporty's or from Wal Mart or etc. "

Comment: I don't know the answers here, just wondering if our definition of "resource location" is perhaps not a little too broad-- and inconsistently applied--

Comment: There have been some other "how do I find" questions that I've found to be extremely helpful-- I'll try to see if I can jog my memory and come up w/ them to post as more examples--